# Противник или противница (о стране)

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подскажите, как правильнее сказать: "страна-противник" или "страна-противница"?

Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 1):

> Страна-противница перестала существовать... Страна-противница
>   представлена в виде...

http://telegrafua.com/world/12889 и https://expert.ru/ural/2014/09/korotko/media/225716/

Другое сочетание (через дефис) не встретилось — только не как связка: »*Древняя страна, противник Ассирии*». Будете первопечатником слова, если употребите.

P. S. По подсказке (см. комментарии) обнаружил не так много (четыре), но нужные примеры, которые уравновесили востребованность версий: «*Будет ли страна-противник выполнять Законы войны...*»; «*Страна-противник предпринимает симметричные меры*», и др.

Comment: А мне "страна-противник" встретилось 7 раз в "гугл-книгах" (смотрел только первые две страницы результатов), а "страна-противница" (-агрессорша, -неприятельница) - не нашлось.

Comment: Начиная поиск, представлял первый вариант более естественным, однако — вот такие дела. Внесу изменение.